# Reducing NaN results while calculating mean ndvi values using Rasterio

Tags: python, raster, rasterio, nodata

I am calculating ndvi means for each raster in a set of before and after change detection images using rasterio. The code below works but I am getting more than 80% NaN values in either the before or after raster mean ndvi due to cloud masking.
How can I edit the code to reduce the number of NaN values while computing ndvi mean values?

```
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show
bf = []
af = []
dates =[]
swarmpoints_path = 'Laikipia_Shrubland_2020'
## loop though the dir
for file in os.listdir(swarmpoints_path):
    # if before is in the file name, then extract mean and add to the list
    if 'before' in file:
        path = os.path.join(swarmpoints_path, file)
        print(path)
        before0 = rasterio.open(path)
        bf_ndvi = before0.read([14])
        bf_mean = bf_ndvi.mean()
        print(bf_mean)
        print(type(bf_mean))
        bf.append(bf_mean)
        date = file.split('_')[-1].split('.')[0]
        dates.append(date)
    # if after is in the file name, extract mean and add to list
    if 'after' in file:
        path = os.path.join(swarmpoints_path, file)
        print(path)
        after0 = rasterio.open(path)
        af_ndvi = after0.read([14])
        af_mean = af_ndvi.mean()
        af.append(af_mean)
        print(af_mean)
    else:
        print( file + ' ' + 'skipped')

        
        
#create a dataframe from lists of mean
import pandas as pd  
# create columns bf_mean, af_mean
data ={'bf_mean':bf, 'af_mean':af}
# create df
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = dates)
df
```

Comment: [numpy.nanmean](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html) perhaps?

Comment: @user2856 thanks a lot it worked for me. Applying the mean on either axis 1 or 0 introduces the NaN so I will use the default setting. Thanks again!